# RadGrid grid columns collection has only 1 row, no name, in ItemDataBound event. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

I am trying to execute some logic in the `RadGrid1_ItemDataBound` event method.  I need the index of a specific column (ImageUrl).  In trying to locate this column, I have tried several different methods. In all cases, the column collection of the `RadGrid` contains 1 column, with a blank name.

My code is as follows:

```
private int GetColumnIndexByName(RadGrid grid, string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (grid.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This method is called from the above mentioned event using the name of the grid and the column name string.  Why is the grid column collection practically empty?

Comment: Have you tried `RowDataBound` event to achieve this?

Comment: That event applies to grieview controls.  The RadGrid control does not have that event available.

Comment: If you look into `RadGrid1_ItemDataBound` event, it automatically loops through all row, you don't have to explicitly loop through all rows like you did in `GetColumnIndexByName`, is there any specif purpose behind this?